# Controls used to create the GUI in this picture

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

Can someone please help me with the names of the forms controls used to create the GUI elements highlighted in the below picture?

[image]

I am needing to create a form that is similar, and I am not sure of the names and types of the controls?

Also, is there a downloadable project that I can use that will simplify this process?

Thanks.

Comment: Left is a TreeView, middle is a DataGrid right is just some static labels, all are WPF.

Comment: It is a quite weird question! This interface can be created in many different ways. You might even just rely on very simple controls (i.e., Panels, Labels, Buttons & imageholders, like a PictureBox). But the most logical approach would be also accounting for more complex ones, like TreeView and ListView/DatagridView (in WPF: DataGrid).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try to use a `TreeView` (left), a `ListView` (mid) a `Panel` containing some arranged `Label`s (right) and a `Panel` containing a `Label` a `TextBox` and two `Button`s (bottom)?

I don't think that Microsoft has build reusable controls for this form like a `NewProjectFormBottomPanelWithTwoButtonControl` or anything.

Comment: Thanks. How about the control on the left. I am referring to the control with the "Recent", "Installed" and "Online" tabs with the arrows. Is this a common windows forms control?

Comment: No, I don't know any common Winforms Control for that. But by the way, DevExpress released that control named "Accordion Control" recently (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gkty9XQcd-4). They have a set of free WinForms controls, maybe it's in there as well. The NavBar control (which is what you know from Outlook) is free, I know.