# Can someone please inform me of the control in this image?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

Can someone please inform me of the correct tabbed control that is in the below image:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you please be more specific about your question?

Comment: This is called tab control and it is WPF not winforms.

Comment: @dotctor Winforms has also TabControl. WPF is not adding anything to Winforms regarding basic functionalities (e.g., controls), its most important contribution (for those liking it; not my case) was introducing a new way to relate controls and the associated data. WPF is just a different way to do things, which doesn't add any real value to those used to the previous methodology.

Comment: Why do you keep asking questions about the Visual Studio GUI (your previous one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32475343/controls-used-to-create-the-gui-in-this-picture)? There is just one answer for all your requests: learn how to use the given language properly and better don't expect magical, this-solve-it-all solutions. C# (in any of its versions; equivalently to any other generic programming language) provides the adequate framework to create anything in many different ways. The only way to adequately maximise it is by being experienced enough: write code and stop asking.

Comment: Clarification for WPF-lovers: Winforms is still the desktop-based C# alternative most widely used. For example, here in SO, any C# (or VB.NET or any other .NET language) question without further mention is assumed to be C# Winforms (the winforms tag is not used in a big proportion of the cases); while the WPF tag has to be added to avoid confusions.

Answer (score 2):

There are different alternatives to create interface elements as the one shown in your picture and the most standard way is using [`TabControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx).

But standard [`TabControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) does't have functionalities like docking, pinning and close button. So if you really need such functionality you can create such component or consider using this open source library:

> **[DockPanelSuite](http://dockpanelsuite.com/)**
>   DockPanel Suite - The Visual Studio inspired docking library for .NET
>   WinForms

Screenshot:

[image]

**Additional Resource:**

- [A good article about using component set](http://www.independent-software.com/weifenluo-dockpanelsuite-tutorial-cookbook/)
- [SockPanelSuite Wiki](https://github.com/dockpanelsuite/dockpanelsuite/wiki)

Comment: Thanks. I have added the DockPanelSuite via NuGet from the following link: https://www.nuget.org/packages/DockPanelSuite/2.9.0. How that I have added it, how can I add this form control to my project to use in my project? I have had a look in the toolbox, yet cannot see it.

Comment: @user3736648  You’ll need to add this control to your Toolbox. In order to so, right-click on your Toolbox and select “Choose Items…”. This gives you a long list of .NET Framework Components already installed, or available through loaded assemblies. The DockPanel won’t be there yet, so use the “Browse…” button to find the WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking.dll. Finally select the DockPanel component and make sure that the checkbox next to it is checked. The new UserControl will now be added to your Toolbox.

Comment: @user3736648 I edited the answer and added Additional Resource. Please read [a good article about using component set](http://www.independent-software.com/weifenluo-dockpanelsuite-tutorial-cookbook/) that is a good start poit :)

Comment: What are you exactly referring to with "It is not a component available in windows forms toolbox"? The picture seems to be displaying a TabControl (= one of the default Winforms controls). Additionally, why recommending external libraries without even knowing what is being expected? The default .NET resources are huge; why looking for more rather than learning how to use what you already have?

Comment: @varocarbas It means it is not a standard control provided by .Net framework. Do you suggest any better description? :)

Comment: LOL. I meant that if the question is "how can I have this interface in C# Winforms?" Your answer "It is not a component available in windows forms toolbox" seems to indicate that the displayed interface element (i.e., apparently a TabControl) is not one of the default Winforms controls (what is not true). If your intention was only recommending this DockPanelSuite as a possible alternative, I would better re-phrase your answer to make it more clear.

Comment: @varocarbas I assumed that the author of question knows standard tab control, because he has not taken a picture of standard tab control, Instead he has taken a picture of visual studio tab, so may be he need such functionality. Close buttons, pin buttons,docking functionality and ...

Comment: I know this OP from a previous question and am not so sure about your assumption. In any case, this has to be clear to any future reader too (independently upon their knowledge). I have slightly changed your answer to reflect these ideas: what you think?

Comment: This is your answer. I just modified it to easily transmit what I meant; you are free to accept my suggestions. Just as a comment: docking is a standard property for all the controls (and also for TabControl; well... for the associated TabPage in this case), the close button might be easily included (= by adding a button closing the form and calling it close button :)); regarding pinning I am not sure about the exact extent of this functionality, but replicating it should be more or less easy. Not trying to criticise, just pointing out some issues which might not be too clear.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your question correctly it is just a sample TabControl 
With a uniqe visual studio style to the header

Comment: Technically, you are correct with the screenshot showing something tha looks just like a TabStrip/TabControl. But as all who use Visual Studio know, it ain't... ;-)